# Restrict access to some endpoints on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, proxy, network-programming, vpn

I have a k8s cluster that runs my app (gce as an ingress) and I want to restrict access to some endpoints "/test/*" but all other endpoints should be publically available. I don't want to restrict for specific IP's to have some flexibility and ability to access restricted endpoints from any device like phones.

I considered IAP but it restricts access to the full service when I need it only for some endpoints. Hence extra.

I have thought about VPN. But I don't understand how to set this up, or would it even resolve my issues.

I have heard about proxy but seems to me it can't fulfill my requirements (?)

I can't tell that solution should be super extensible or generic because only a few people will use this feature.

I want the solution to be light, flexible, simple, and fulfill my needs at the same time. So if you say that there are solutions but it's complex I would consider restricting access by the IP, but I worry about how the restricted IP's approach is viable in the real life. In a sense would it be too cumbersome to add the IP of my phone every time I change my location and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up OpenVPN.

It was not a tedious process because of the various small obstacles but I encourage you to do the same.

1. Get a host (machine, cluster, or whatever) with the static IP
2. Setup an OpenVPN instance. I do docker  https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/openvpn/ (follow instructions but update a host -u YOUR_IP)
3. Ensure that VPN setup works from your local machine
4. To the routes you need limit IP access to the VPN one. Nginx example

```
allow x.x.x.x;
deny all;
```

5. Make sure that nginx treats IP right. I had an issue that the nginx was having Load Balancer IP as client IP's, so I have to put some as trusted. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html
6. Test the setup

Answer (score 2):

You can use [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) for that. It approximatively meets your needs, it's not so flexible and simple.

But it's fully managed and can scale with your traffic.

For a more convenient solution, you have to use software proxy (or API Gateway), or go to the Bank and use [Apigee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee)